# Redis Labs ad redirects to a 404

Tags: support, advertising

Stack Overflow is running an ad for Redis Labs (sorry, missed the opportunity to take a screenshot) that has a broken link that results in a 404 error: https://redislabs.com/docs/microservices-redis-enterprise-kubernetes?utm_source=SO&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=kubernetes_wp

This probably isn't Stack Overflow's fault, but someone here may want to reach out to Redis Labs and let them know they're probably not getting their money's worth with this ad.

Comment: Apparently, the bare link https://redislabs.com/docs/microservices-redis-enterprise-kubernetes without params will redirect to https://redislabs.com/docs/microservices-on-kubernetes/ (just a remark in case someone is still interested in knowing that ad)

Comment: Even the form on that link is broken :-/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks so much for flagging this. I work on the ops teams and the 404 error has been communicated to Redis Labs.